# Is it ok that my hanging ceiling lamp isn't grounded?

Tags: electrical, lamp

I have a ceiling lamp that needs to hang about 12 inches below due to slanted ceiling.  I bought a canopy that covers up the box and extended the hot & neutral wires to the lamp itself using a regular lamp wire.  However, the ground wire isn't connected. Is that OK?

A little more explanation about how it is hung.  The lamp has a metal case, which is hung via 5 steel wires, attaching to a zinc-plated link, which is attached to the chandelier mounting kit.  The mounting kit is attached to the metal gang box, for which I had the ground wire connected.  Come to think of it, any electric short would have come through this path....?

[image]

Comment: Pictures might make it a little clearer>  Thanks

Comment: What is physically carrying the weight  of the lamp? Wires are not for that.

Comment: Posted picture now... took me a while to draw it.  The metallic gang box is used to carries the weight of the lamp.  That part I'm not worried about.

Comment: The wire from the ceiling has hot, neutral, and ground.  Only hot & neutral wires were attached to the lamp wire.  The ground wire is currently hooked to the gang box itself.

Comment: The picture isn't quite accurate since the ceiling is actually slanted.  Other than that, I'm fairly satisfied with my drawing skills :-)

Comment: Is there room to stuff another wire up the fixture nipple (i.e. the part that passes the wires through the canopy)?

Comment: There could be a little room but because everything is already hung so disassembling it is a big job...  What is the risk involved here without doing anything?

Comment: How often do you expect to change light bulbs?  One of the risks is getting a small shock that only stuns, except you're up a ladder and you fall.

Comment: have you ever seen a portable lamp that's grounded? Are your wires mis-wired? Do you normally grab the metal of the lamp while touching a grounded piece of metal? Why wouldn't the metal box be connected to the metal wires hanging the lamp? in short, this is fine, unless you're wiring is borked.

Comment: I probably won't change light bulb too often... probably once every 8-10 years if the LED package label does not lie.  I'm fairly certain that the hot/neutral wires are connected correctly.  Since it's hung from the high ceiling, I would never ever touch it unless I need to change any light bulb.  Even so, I could just switch off the lamp when changing light bulbs.